# Searching for data in a linked list

Tags: c++, struct, linked-list, ifstream

The first part of my program is to extract specific data from a file and insert it into a linked list. I successfully created that part of the program but I'm having difficulty searching through my linked list and printing data. This is my code so far:

```
struct Country
 {
  string  name;
  double  population;
 };

struct Node 
 {
  Country ctry;
  Node *next;
 };
Node *world;

void makeList(Node *&world);
void printCountry (Node *&world, string name);

int main ()
{
    string name;

    makeList(world);
    printCountry (world, name);
    return 0;
}

void makeList(Node *world)
{
    ifstream inFile("population.csv");

    if (!inFile.fail())
    {
        cout << "File has opened successfully." << endl;
    }
    else
    {
        cout << "File has failed to open." << endl;
        exit(1);
    }

   double temp, temp1, temp2, temp3, population;
   string countryName;

   Node *top = new Node; 
   world = top;

   while (!inFile.eof())
   {
        top -> next = NULL;

        inFile >> temp >> temp1 >> temp2 >> temp3 >> population;
        getline (inFile, countryName);

        top -> ctry.population = population;
        top -> ctry.name = countryName;

        if (!inFile.eof())
        {
            top -> next = new Node;
            top = top -> next;
        }
   } 

   // check if list is created successfully
   while (world -> next != NULL)
   {
    cout << world -> ctry.population << "   " << world -> ctry.name << endl;
    world = world -> next;
   }
}

void printCountry (Node *world, string name)
{
    string countryToFind;

    cout << "What country do you want to find? " << endl;
    cin >> countryToFind;

    while (world != NULL) 
    {
        if (world -> ctry.name == countryToFind)
        {
            cout << "Country has been found: " << world -> ctry.name << " has a population of "
                 << world -> ctry.population << endl;
            break;
        }

        else
        {
            if (world -> next == NULL)
            {
                cout << "End of file" << endl;
                break;
            }
            world = world -> next;
        }
    } 
}
```

When I run the printCountry, it just searches through the list and prints End of file. What did I do wrong in the printCountry?

Comment: If you're going to post code, do try and make it your *real* code. (copy/paste is the order of the day). Ex: You declare `makeList` as  `void makeList(Node *& world)`, yet the implementation has no reference, only a pointer type: `void makeList(Node *world)`. The same is true for `printCountry`. This will compile, but as-is cannot possibly link.

Comment: `void makeList(Node *&world);` I didnt continue reading after this line, because I dont understand it. Why do you use such strange parameter type?

Comment: @tobi303 the intent is to change the head pointer by-reference. And it would work if that what was actually implemented.

Comment: @WhozCraig oh, i see. Thanks for clarifying. I was a bit consufed on first glance

Answer (score 0):

you should really separate
1) data structure (linked list)
2) CSV parser
3) loading the parsed data to the linked list.

Here's an example using C#.

```
public class LinkedList<T> : IEnumerable<T>
{
    private class Node<T>
    {
        public T Value { get; set; }
        public Node<T> Next { get; set; }
    }

    private Node<T> _startingNode;

    public void Add(T item)
    { 
        //define the next node 
        var nextNode = new Node<T>()
        {
            Value = item
        };

        //add the node to the end
        Node<T> lastNode = this.GetLastNode();
        if (lastNode == null)
        {
            this._startingNode = nextNode;
        }
        else
        {
            lastNode.Next = nextNode;
        }
    }

    public IEnumerator<T> GetEnumerator()
    {
        Node<T> lastNode = this._startingNode;
        while (lastNode != null)
        {
            yield return lastNode.Value;
            if (lastNode.Next == null)
            {
                yield break;
            }
            lastNode = lastNode.Next;
        }
    }

    IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    private Node<T> GetLastNode()
    {
        var lastNode = this._startingNode;
        while (lastNode != null)
        {
            if (lastNode.Next == null)
            {
                break;
            }
            lastNode = lastNode.Next;
        }
        return lastNode;
    }
}


public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        //load the list 
        var numberList = new LinkedList<int>();
        numberList.Add(100);
        numberList.Add(200);
        numberList.Add(300);
        numberList.Add(400);


        //do something with it 
        foreach (var item in numberList)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Item {0}", item);
        }


    }

}
```